# Using a loop to cycle though API calls in R

Tags: r

I have created a simple script to collect a Youtube Channels statistics. Just wondering how I could loop though a list of channel ID's instead of having to manually change the channel ID each time then re-run the script? I struggle to understand how to write loops in R.

```
key <- 'MyKey'
channel_id1 <- 'UCLSWNf28X3mVTxTT3_nLCcw'

url <- 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics'
y <- paste0(url,'&id=',channel_id1,'&key=',key)

yt_channel1 <- fromJSON(txt=y)
yt_d_channel1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(c, unlist(yt_channel1, recursive=FALSE)))
```

Any way to store all channel ID's of interest in a list or vector then loop though them, storing results into new or the same dataframe?

i.e.

```
channels <- c('UCLSWNf28X3mVTxTT3_nLCcw', 'UCLSW467236VTxTT3_nLCcw', UHJKHS328787_ndncp')

for i 1:3, {
channels...
do stuff
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, store the channel IDs in a column in a data frame.  Assuming you have a data frame called `my_data_frame` with a column `ID` that contains the IDs, you can loop through the IDs like this:

```
key <- 'MyKey'
url <- 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics'
for(i in 1:nrow(my_data_frame)){
  y <- paste0(url,'&id=',my_data_frame$ID[i],'&key=',key)
  yt_channel1 <- fromJSON(txt=y)
  yt_d_channel1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(c, unlist(yt_channel1, recursive=FALSE)))
}
```

Notice how the ID is referenced using an index `i` which will count from 1 until the number of rows in your data frame.

Note, this code will not work as you will need to come up with a way to store the results.